# What is the easiest way to fill std::array of int with elements of std::array of double with proper casting?

Tags: c++, casting, stdarray

I want to use `std::array<double, 4>` in function that uses `std::array<int, 4>`?

So, what is the **easiest** / **shortest**(both of them) way to achieve that.

E.g.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void printInts(std::array<int, 4> someInts) {
    for(int someInt : someInts) {    
        std::cout << someInt << std::endl;
    }
}

std::array<double, 4> someDoubles{1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};

int main() {
    printInts(someDoubles); // of course it doesn't work
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot for every help ;)

P.S

```
1
2
3
4
```

will be expected output of course.

Comment: That depends on what you want. Do you want to accept an `array` of any type, and print it as `int`s?

Comment: @cigien I cannot change function declaration. I think about creation of `std::array<int, 4>` and some initialization of it with array of doubles.

Comment: @dfri Yeah, it's OK for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't change the function `PrintInts`, then you could just create an `int` version of the array, and call the function with that:

```
std::array<int, 4> ints;
std::copy(std::begin(someDoubles), std::end(someDoubles), std::begin(ints));
printInts(ints);
```

Be aware that converting from `double` to `int` could lose precision due to the narrowing conversion. This could even result in UB if the converted `double` value cannot be represented by an `int`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5HA85F).

Comment: You may want to point out that there is not only a loss of precision at stake here, but that it is, as per [\[conv.fpint\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.fpint#1), UB if the truncated value cannot be represented in the target integer type (here: `int`).

Answer (score 1):

**cigien** suggested a good short way to fill an `std::array<int, N>` with values from `std::array<double, N>`.
However, if you want a dedicated named function that *returns* `std::array<int, N>`, then it would be something like

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void printInts(const std::array<int, 4> &someInts) {
    for (int someInt : someInts) {
        std::cout << someInt << std::endl;
    }
}

template <size_t N>
std::array<int, N> castToInts(const std::array<double, N> &someDoubles) {
    std::array<int, N> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        result[i] = static_cast<int>(someDoubles[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

std::array<double, 4> someDoubles{ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };

int main() {
    printInts(castToInts(someDoubles)); // now we can call like this
    return 0;
}
```

If you want more simplicity, you can delete `template <size_t N>` and hardcode **4** instead of **N**.

By the way, I changed your `printInts` a bit, look up about *passing object parameters by reference*.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest because it's a couple small changes to make `printInts` do what you want:

```cpp
void printAsInts(std::array<double, 4> someDoubles) {
    for (double someDouble : someDoubles) {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(someDouble) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Shortest (and arguably easy) because it relies on facilities provided by the standard library, so you don't even need to write a loop:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

std::array<double, 4> someDoubles{1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};

int main() {
    std::transform(someDoubles.begin(), someDoubles.end(),
                   std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"),
                   [](double x) { return static_cast<int>(x); });
    return 0;
}
```

The above is slightly more efficient than some of the other answers, too, since it doesn't have to make a second array.  With only four elements, a second array isn't a large cost, but if the size of the array large, then you probably don't want to instantiate a temporary one.  It's also more efficient since `std::endl` requires the output buffer to be flushed more often than it needs to be.

More general.  Admittedly, this is not the easiest or shortest to write, but, once written, it's the easiest to use and it provides a lot of flexibility because you can change the type of the container without touching the print code.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename Iter>
void printAs(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    std::transform(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\n"),
                   [](const auto &x) { return static_cast<T>(x); });
}

template<typename T, typename Container>
void printAs(const Container &container) {
    printAs<T>(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
}

std::array<double, 4> someDoubles{1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};

int main() {
    printAs<int>(someDoubles);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively: `std::for_each(begin, end, [](auto const& x) { std::cout << ...; })` looks slightly simpler to me ;)